# Getting Rails 3 working with minimum hassle on Windows 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am looking at a few different ways to get Rails 3 working (database is not important right now) on Windows 7, would appreciate some advice on different stacks and IDEs. I do want to go with an IDE for several reasons such as code completion and because i will be using the ruby debugger (which i find easier to use on a GUI)

Netbeans for Ruby 7.0 m2, seems like the easiest route so far.

Aptana 3/Radrails, tried this last night, had a few problems already, it seems Rails does not work out-of-box, at least when i tried creating a new Rails project, nothing seemed to happen.

Rubystack with Notepad++/Gvim, might be overkill/less than ideal, but if it works better than the rest, i'm happy.

Turnkey Linux/Jumpbox/Elastic server, all of these are currently a bit out of date, as i wanted to get into Rails 3, so only Rubystack seems like it fits that criteria so far.

Rubymine. Didn't really look at this yet, but wanted to avoid paying unless it really turned out to be the best overall option.

Ubuntu, yeah might end up dual-booting or at least using the Bitnami Rubystack VM in VMware, though i tried this and had a couple of issues getting Rails to work/connect to the guest OS. If i dual-booted, would this involve significantly less effort than getting Rails to run in Win7? Yes, i'm already experienced with Linux, Ubuntu in particular, but my main work machine is Win7-based (for now)

(already posted on programmers.stackexchange.com, no worthwhile responses received)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we have many happy users developing with RubyStack on Windows 7. It is self-contained, so if for whatever reason it does not work for you, simply run the uninstaller and it is gone from your system. As a side bonus, it includes a full install of Git, etc.